# android countdown timer from remote server

Tags: java, php, android, api

actually i am making a game application in android where I need a countdown timer in one of my activities, which I can make from handler but the scene is it should be updated from remote server so is there any way to run any kind of script at php level which provides updated value everytime app fetches the API.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would store the initial time for that device in the server and just give the difference of current time - saved time using the server time for both values. Remember to not give any control to the client over that timer as it would be open to security issues due to client tampering depending on your application functionality.

Comment: ok got it but i am not so good with php so could you just provide me any link or anything that could help me getting this thing done...but your answer is right as  far as my requirements are concerned

Comment: Try using microtime to get the timestamp in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php you will need to have a way to store the device id in order to save it's start time and then compare it later on to current time. Do you have a database in your application? Maybe try starting with mySQL database, that one is very often used with PHP

Comment: my database is in remote servers hosting

Comment: If you have accounts just store the account id along with the start time. And query the start time whenever you get the api request. You can use this doc to use mySQL with PHP https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp